# Groovy: how to override time unit of @TimedInterrupt in an ASTTransformationCustomizer?

Tags: groovy, scripting, abstract-syntax-tree, groovyscriptengine

I'm using Groovy 4.0.2 as a runtime scripting environment for my application. My goal is to introduce timeout handling into user-provided scripts, but depending on what the script is used for, different timeouts should apply. My compiler configuration looks as follows:

```java
var config = new CompilerConfiguration();
var extensions = new ArrayList<String>()
var timedInterruptParams = new HashMap<String, Object>()
// TimedInterrupt is an annotation with multiple parameters. We're only interested
// in the "value" and the "unit" parameters. For now, let's only set the "value"...
timedInterruptParams.put("value", myTimeout);

config.addCompilationCustomizers(
    new ASTTransformationCustomizer(CompileStatic.class),
    new ASTTransformationCustomizer(timedInterruptParams, TimedInterrupt.class)
);
```

The above configuration works, but it fixes the `unit` of the `TimedInterrupt` to its default (which is `TimeUnit.SECONDS`). I would like to overwrite this value in the `timedInterruptParams` map. However, none of the following works:

- `timedInterruptParams.put("unit", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`

  Produces an error during script compilation, claiming that `MILLISECONDS` is not a supported constant expression.
- `timedInterruptParams.put("unit", new ConstantExpression(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`

  Same as above
- `timedInterruptParams.put("unit", "MILLISECONDS")`

  Causes the groovy compiler to bug out completely with "this method should not have been called".
- `timedInterruptParams.put("unit", "java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS")`

  Same as above

So... I'm running out of options here. Which value am I supposed to pass into the `"unit"` value of the parameter map?

Comment: Could you please create a ticket in the Groovy JIRA so we can fix the handling of enum values?  It should work for TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS with no ast wrapping, but as mentioned below fails to be converted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took quite a bit of digging, but the answer lied within `TimedInterruptibleASTTransformation`, the class which actually interprets the `@TimedInterrupt` annotation. There, the `unit` value was interpreted as follows:

```
Expression unit = node.getMember('unit') ?: propX(classX(TimeUnit), 'SECONDS')
```

... and `propX` and `classX` are static helper methods from `org.codehaus.groovy.ast.tools.GeneralUtils`. With this information, it was relatively easy to make my code work. The line I was missing is:

```java
timedInterruptParams.put("unit", propX(classX(TimeUnit.class), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toString()),
```

It turns out that groovy interprets enum literals not as constants, but as properties of a class. This case sadly isn't covered by the auto-converter that applies to the object values of the parameter maps.